# Верное окончание

Tags: глаголы

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать: 1) "Здесь найдЕТСЯ и тетрадь, и карандаш, и линейка". 2) "Здесь найдУТСЯ и тетрадь, и карандаш, и линейка". Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше использовать форму единственного числа: найдется. Такое решение связано с инверсией главных членов (сказуемое перед подлежащим) и неактивным характером каждого подлежащего.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Подскажите, а есть какое-либо правило на этот счет?

Comment: Да, есть. Эта тема называется "Выбор формы сказуемого при однородных подлежащих". Правда, ссылки у меня нет, я смотрю по книге "Современный русский язык", учебник для вузов.

Comment: София, спасибо вам за название темы. Нашла здесь подобную. http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm И, честно говоря, я в замешательстве. Я не думала, что существует столько нюансов. Признаюсь, не до конца понимаю почему где-то множественное число, а где-то единственное. Например: 1)"До Райского и Марфиньки долетел грубый говор, грубый смех, смешанные голоса, внезапно притихшие"; 2)"Снаружи были слышны визг, лай и вой".

Comment: Ммарина, надеюсь, ваше замешательство уменьшится, когда поймете, что нюансов не так и много, а главное они не носят императивного характера. Оба варианта правильны, один предпочтительнее, выбор определяется не столько грамматикой, сколько стилистикой. 
Это в полной мере относится к Вашим примерам. Скорее всего во втором автор передает совместное действие "визга, лая и воя", а в первом - самостоятельное, пусть и единовременное. Разница -  не формализуемая, на уровне авторского понимания.

На всякий случай. Ссылка у Вас на Розенталя-Джанжакову.
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/20.htm

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!